# How can i disable swipe refresh layout when RecyclerView is not on the first item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using swiperefreshlayout and recyclerview in my project. i want swiperefreshlayout disable when recyclerview not on the first item. how can i do it?
I have some code but it didn't work:

```
int topRowVerticalPosition = (myRecyclerView == null || myRecyclerView.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : myRecyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0 && topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an OnScrollListener to the `RecyclerView` like so, and you can enable/disable the swipeRefreshLayout using the `RecyclerView`s first child's visibility:

```
myRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
  @Override
  public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    View firstChild = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(firstChild.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
  }
});
```

Comment: @Farid can you share what you tried but isn't working?

Comment: newsRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
            {
                View firstChild = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
   swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(firstChild.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

Answer (score 1):

Basically checking if the first visible item index `== 0` is not correct, because you can hide it, My solution to this problem is to check the index if the first visible child is completely visible inside the recycler.

```
val isScrolledToTop = layout.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == indexOfChild(children.firstOrNull { it.isVisible }))
```

so you can combine it with a listener to enable Swipe to refresh.

```kotlin
binding.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        val isScrolledToTop = layout.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == indexOfChild(children.firstOrNull { it.isVisible }))
        binding.swipeToRefresh.isEnabled = isScrolledToTop
    }
}
```